# docker-compose up doesn't exit when containers stopped

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running some services through docker-compose, and launching them with systemd:

```
$ systemctl status nextcloud.service
● nextcloud.service - HomelabOS nextcloud Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nextcloud.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Wed 2021-12-08 23:49:07 EST; 5min ago
    Process: 402260 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f /var/homelabos/docker-compose.nextcloud.yml -p nextcloud stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES>
   Main PID: 3128 (docker-compose)
      Tasks: 22 (limit: 38376)
     Memory: 12.8M
        CPU: 8.704s
     CGroup: /system.slice/nextcloud.service
             └─3128 /usr/bin/docker-compose -f /var/homelabos/docker-compose.nextcloud.yml -p nextcloud up --build
...
```

As you can see, the containers have been killed successfully, and other commands say the same thing:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/docker-compose -f /var/homelabos/docker-compose.nextcloud.yml -p nextcloud ps
NAME                       COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
nextcloud-nextcloud-1      "/entrypoint.sh /usr…"   nextcloud           exited (137)        
nextcloud-nextcloud_db-1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   nextcloud_db        exited (0)  
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
363f0b6c5e24   grafana/grafana   "/run.sh"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   3000/tcp   grafana-grafana-1
```

The problem here is that `docker-compose up` is still running! How do I get it to stop doing that, and instead stop when the containers it manages are stopped, i.e. the original behavior?

Comment: Can't you use `-d` flag?

Comment: I also need it to print the containers' logs to stdout so it is picked up by syslog. With `-d`, that no longer happens.

Comment: I noticed that in my version it gets "stuck" running even after I Ctrl-C on the command line, and all containers are reported as "stopped". I have begun to suspect that this might be a bug in Docker Compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a bug in docker compose v2.2.0.](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9003) Downgrading to v2.1.1 should fix the issue.

[It now also appears to be fixed in v2.2.3](https://github.com/docker/compose/commit/740276f550ecb7da444b20dc21860ce2f2c547d6).